# AIX Interactive Shell

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

I was hoping I could distinguish between when a script is run interactively versus by 'at' or 'cron'.  If the user is running a script on the command line I want to put output to their screen, but if it's running via 'at' or 'cron' then the output would go to a log file.

I searched online and saw many suggestions (although not AIX specific) on using the "$-".  That sounded promising, but when I tried it, it wasn't as useful.

If I type 'echo "$-"' at the prompt I get "ims" back.  If I create a script with the echo command, it returns "h".  If I submit the script via "at" I get "h", and if I have cron run it I get "h".

I also looked at using TERM and PS1, but again they don't allow me to distinguish between a script run by either 'cron' or 'at' versus a script invoked at the command line.

Is there something else I could try on AIX?

Thanks.

If I run this script

Glenn.  Here's a script I'm running.  I get the desired result using "tty -s" but not with "$-".  Am I doing something wrong?  You see the "$-" results always says I'm not in an interactive shell.

```
   #!/bin/ksh93
   echo "tty -s"
   if tty -s 
   then 
      echo "   - I'm an interactive shell"
   else 
      echo "   - I'm not interactive"
   fi
   echo "\$-"
   case $- in
   *i*) echo "   - I'm an interactive shell";;
   *)   echo "   - I'm not interactive";;
   esac
```

I get these three results sets when the script is run via 1) the command line, 2) "at", and 3) cron.

```
command line result

tty -s
   - I'm an interactive shell
$-
   - I'm not interactive

at result

tty -s
   - I'm not interactive
$-
   - I'm not interactive

Cron result

tty -s
   - I'm not interactive
$-
   - I'm not interactive
```

By running at the command line I mean I'm running "script.ksh >> script.log".  If I run "echo $-" from the command line it returns 'ims' but when $- is reference within a script it always returns 'h'.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if `$-` *contains* the letter `i`. If it does, you have an interactive shell:

```
case $- in
*i*) echo "I'm an interactive shell";;
*)   echo "I'm not interactive";;
esac
```

Testing

```
$ ksh
$ case $- in
> *i*) echo "I'm an interactive shell";;
> *)   echo "I'm not interactive";;
> esac
I'm an interactive shell

$ ksh <<'END'
> case $- in
> *i*) echo "I'm an interactive shell";;
> *)   echo "I'm not interactive";;
> esac
> END
I'm not interactive
```

---

Given the comments below, you probably want to use this builtin test:

```sh
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    : # script running interactively
else
    # running non-interactively (cron or at)
    # redirect output to a log file
    exec 1>/path/to/logfile 2>&1
fi
# and now, your script can just output to stdout/stderr
# and the output will go to the screen or to the logfile
echo "hello"
date
print -u2 "bye"
```

Comment: I did try using "$-" (see original post).   It returns "ims" when I type "echo '$-'" at the command line,  but if I put that line in a script and run the script the value changes to "h".  It's also "h" when I run the script via 'at' or as a cron job.   I want to be able to differentiate between when a script is run from then command line versus when it's run via 'at' or 'cron'.

Comment: I know. I read that. You don't want to look at the entire contents of `$-`. As I write above, you need to check if `$-` **contains** the letter `i`

Comment: Glenn. I edited the original question to show you the results I get with "$-" and "tty -s".   "$-" is always saying in not interactive.

Comment: I'll be out of the office for the next 15 days, so I won't reply to any questions until the 21st. Thx.

Comment: The `tty` command simply lets you know if stdin is coming from a terminal. Compare `sh -c 'tty -s && echo interactive || echo not'` versus `sh -c 'tty -s && echo interactive || echo not' </dev/null`

Comment: In retrospect, you want to know if there's probably a human there, so using `tty` is a good choice.

Comment: Although there is a ksh builtin test: `ksh '[ -t 0 ] && echo interactive || echo not'`
versus `ksh '[ -t 0 ] && echo interactive || echo not' </dev/null` -- that tests if file descriptor zero (stdin) is a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> If the user is running a script on the command line I want to put output to their screen, but if it's running via 'at' or 'cron' then the output would go to a log file.

That's what standard output and redirection is good for. Also you can use command `tty -s` to determine if your standard input is a terminal or not. (If you wish to check your *standard output* instead: `tty -s <&1`)

Example (~projects/tmp/tty_test.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

exec >>~projects/tmp/tty_test.log 2>&1

tty

if tty -s; then echo terminal
else            echo otherwise
fi
```

Comment: tty -s doesn't allow me to differentiate between when a script is run from the command line versus when it's run via 'at' or 'cron'.   Regardless of how I run the script, 'tty -s' returns 0, indicating interactive.  Am I missing something?  I want it so, when the script is run at the command line the output comes to the screen, but if it's run via 'at' or 'cron' it should go to a file.

Comment: Got it working now.  I was incorrectly using "if [[ $(tty -s) -eq 0 ]] which is obviously (well, now at least) incorrect.  Thanks.